# Somewhere to be dead or somewhere to die?

Tags: phrase-choice

Which is the correct sentence? Somewhere to be Dead or Somewhere to Die?

But what if I use "Somewhere to be dead" instead? I would like to use this for my video game title

Comment: Somewhere to be dead is a morgue or a cemetery.

Comment: I agree that it sounds like a cemetery. Is this what you have in mind? It also sounds a little clumsy.

Comment: Yeah, i know we're all gonna die in a cemetery. But what i mean here is different. My theme is a post apocalyptic world, so what's in my mind is "Somewhere" to represent the tragic death of the people of the apocalypse in a various way and place (ex: shot in the head and left alone in a basement).

Answer (score 1):

**Dead** is an adjective: it describes something which is not alive. It is a state or condition. Typical places to *be dead* include cemeteries.

**Die** is a verb: it is the action of becoming dead. Typical places *to die* include hospital beds, wars, wrecked cars, etc.